# C simple input Questions

Tags: c, input

Given a case like below :

```
2
+

-1
3
5

-2
4
6

-

-10
0
1
2
3

0
2
4
6
```

The input consists of the number of test cases, m, in the first line and followed by m groups of an operator and two lists of sorted integers in a strictly increasing order.

I want to store the integer in two list, but I have problem how to determine when the second list is needed. Is there any method that I can use "\n" as a point to determine the use of second list.

```
int main()
{
int cases;
scanf("%d\n", &cases);
printf("%d\n", cases);

char temp[100];
while(fgets(temp, 100, stdin) != NULL){
    if(strcmp(temp, "+\n") == 0)
        printf("operator");
    if(strcmp(temp, "\n") == 0)
        printf("blank line");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. You can add your code into the question with the [edit] button.

Comment: Short answer: Sure. Just check for two consecutive `\n`'s.

Comment: What is `-10` paired with? It seems out of place? (that would give you 5 numbers is list 1 and 4 numbers in list 2 for your 2nd case)

Comment: it is normal, two given list is not required to have same numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your question - it seems like you are provided with test cases. In case as you know there are possibly no chance of getting bad input - you can do simple things.

First input is a number denoting the number of testcases - so you can do use `scanf` over here to get the input (Infact you can read this using a `fgets` too and convert it using `atoi`/`strtol`). Once you get it, use `fgets` to read each line.

Now how you check that it is operator or number? You can check the content of the line. For operator it can be as simple as checking the first character of the input line.

How do you understand that you are getting a different group? It is observable that there is a blank line containing `\n` in between groups of numbers. So when you get that you can be sure that for input of one group is being taken. 
The same way like this, you can understand about the list that you are getting as input.

Converting those numbers which are taken as string can be done using `atoi` or `strtol`(Better choice as providing error checking).

Understanding when input ends can be done by checking the return value of `fgets` it will return `NULL` when there is nothing to read.

Comment: why it cannot find the blank line? any wrong on my code

Comment: @gamegame.: It is a line which contains `\n`....if you check it then you can find it for sure.

Comment: oh, i make some mistakes

Comment: @gamegame.: yes or simply `temp[0]=='\n'`